# Can someone explain to me ,what they did? (Analysis) (induction)

Tags: analysis, induction

It's a prove by induction and I don't understand how they did the proof, especially I do not understand the red.

\begin{align}f^{(n+1)}(x)=\left(f^{(n)}\right)'(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}((3^nx+n\cdot 3^{n-1})\cdot e^{3x-1})\\
&=3^n\cdot e^{3x-1}+\color{red}{3}(3^nx+n\cdot3^{n-1})\cdot e^{3x-1}\\
&=(3^n+\color{red}{3^{n+1}}x+\color{red}{n\cdot3^n})\cdot e^{3x-1}\\
&=(\color{red}{3^{n+1}x+(n+1)3^n})\cdot e^{3x-1}\end{align}

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: The red underline simply uses the law of indices $a^n.a^m = a^{n+m}$. Note that a and $a^1$ mean the same thing.

Comment: Do you know how to group terms? Try grouping the terms in line $2$ so that $e^{3x-1}$ is factored and come back if you have any more problems.